# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent c# excel inline

Tags: c#, excel

I have this problem for trying to return a excel inline response.

I searched all through the help coding pages for answers to this and can not find something that works yet.

I made a simplified example of what I am doing below. This issue always happen.

Error in this line:

```
Line 56:         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PleaseWait();
        Call();
    }

    protected void Call()
    {
        strSql = "SELECT * FROM ....... ; ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

        GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename= "Output.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    protected void PleaseWait()
    {
        this.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=8>");
        this.Response.Write(@"<style type=text/css media=all>");
        this.Response.Write(@".loading");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"text-align: center;");
        this.Response.Write(@"padding-top: 30px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"border-width: 1px solid #000;");
        this.Response.Write(@"width: 300px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"height: 100px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"-ms-filter: alpha(opacity=90);");
        this.Response.Write(@"-ms-opacity: 0.90;");
        this.Response.Write(@"border-style: solid;");
        this.Response.Write(@"background-color: #FFFFFF;");
        this.Response.Write(@"position: absolute;");
        this.Response.Write(@"font-family: Trebuchet MS;");
        this.Response.Write(@"font-size: small;");
        this.Response.Write(@"position: absolute;");
        this.Response.Write(@"top: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"bottom: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"left: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"right: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"margin: auto;");
        this.Response.Write(@"display: block;");
        this.Response.Write(@"background: url('images/wait01.gif') no-repeat center;");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"</style>");

        this.Response.Write(@"<div id=mydiv class=loading>&nbsp;</div>");
        this.Response.Write(@"<script>mydiv.innerText = '';");
        this.Response.Write(@"</script>");
        this.Response.Write(@"<script language=javascript>;");
        this.Response.Write(@"var dots = 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"var dotmax = 10;");
        this.Response.Write(@"function ShowWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"var output;");
        this.Response.Write(@"output = 'Wait...';");
        this.Response.Write(@"dots++;");
        this.Response.Write(@"if(dots>=dotmax)dots=1;");
        this.Response.Write(@"for(var x = 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"x < dots;x++)");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"output += '.';");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.innerText =  output;");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"function StartShowWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.style.visibility = 'visible'; ");
        this.Response.Write(@"window.setInterval('ShowWait()',1500);");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"function HideWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
        this.Response.Write(@"window.clearInterval();");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"StartShowWait();");
        this.Response.Write(@"</script>");

        this.Response.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
             ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you can't do that. In your `PleaseWait` method, you're calling `Response.Flush`. That sends the currently buffered output, along with the HTTP headers. HTTP headers are always sent before the other response data, so you're out of luck.

The usual way to do this is to have a separate `PleaseWait` page, which does a timed redirect to the actual file (which then only sends the file data along with the proper headers).

The basic issue is that HTTP is "Single request, single response". You're trying to return two responses to a single request, and that simply is not possible over pure HTTP (sadly; there are HTTP-like protocols that allow this, but they aren't really supported in browsers - it's a great boost to performance when you can send 20 files at once, rather than in 20 separate requests).

Comment: thank you for help.

Do you have any example for create a separate PleaseWait page, which does a timed redirect to the actual file ?

Comment: @user3370558 Well, you can simply do a `Response.Redirect` from the "Please wait" page. You still have to split your code into two pages or decide based on eg. a query string - `getData.aspx` could show "Please wait" and do a redirect to `getData.aspx?download=1` which would run `Call` instead of `PleaseWait`.

Comment: thank you, but in the page getData.aspx I've the same problem and the same error ... Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent in this line Line 50:         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

Comment: @user3370558 You have to run either the `PleaseWait` method or the `Call`, never *both* of them in a single request. (also, note that you're not emitting valid XHTML; unless you're using plain HTML, you're bound to get a lot of validation "warnings")

Comment: In the page default.aspx run only the PleaseWait() and redirect to getData.aspx and in getData.aspx run only the Call(). 
Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent in this line Line 50: Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

Comment: @user3370558 Are you actually using `Response.Redirect`? It sounds a lot like you're using `Server.Transfer`. Or perhaps you're using `Response.Flush` before, or perhaps building a lot of data (so that the buffer is flushed automatically). Also, use `Response.BufferOutput` rather than `Response.Buffer`.

Comment: If use in `default.aspx` the `Response.Redirect` I've the error `Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent`. With set `Server.Transfer` I don't have error in `default.aspx` page but error in `gedData.aspx` page

Comment: @Hamamelis Let me try again. Your `PleaseWait` method is sending data, and flushing. This means that the HTTP headers (which `Response.Redirect` uses) have already been sent - those are always the first part of the HTTP response. You can't send them again in the same response, and HTTP is a simple request->response model, so you can't start a new response either. At this point, your only option is to redirect using the *content* of the page, for example by appending `<script>window.location='http://newlocation/something.aspx';</script>`

Comment: @Hamamelis In other words, you've already sent a response (the "please wait" page), you can't start over and send a different response to the same request - it's too late to do that. The point is, the please wait page must be a separate request from the download itself. You can't clear a response that has already been sent.